# Error 400 while trying to read data store in a bucket located in ap-east-1 region with spark

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of code that is used to read/write data from/to a S3 bucket.

After duplicating this code on a new AWS Region (originally deployed on eu-west-1, new deployment occurs on ap-east-1 region). I have the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: SOMEID, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request, S3 Extended Request ID: SOMEREQUESTID
```

After investigation the error is thrown from S3AFileSystem.java at the following line

```
if (!s3.doesBucketExist(bucket)) {
```

Here, a HEAD operation is performed on the bucket. 
After investigation, it appears that endpoint is always https://s3.amazonaws.com and the head request is trigger on https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com, when it should occurs on https://bucket-name.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com (also, `fs.s3a.path.style.access` is `false`)

Specifying the region with `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable does not modify the behavior.

Last information, here are my dependencies as defined in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.3"
```

Needless to say, anytime I point on my bucket in eu-west-1 configuration, the code works.
What should I do (on my code or on my bucket configuration) to allow my code to load files.

For the record, the code is

```
getSparkSession().read.format("csv").option("delimiter", ";").option("header","false").load(path)
```

Comment: Even more curious, forcing endpoint to be "https://s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com" gives the same error ...

Comment: check the endpoint signature version 4 is used.